# Utilize interface or type to describe object's keys

Tags: typescript

Consider I have defined type:

```js
export type RegisterInput = {
  email: Scalars['String'];
  age: Scalars['Int'];
  password: Scalars['String'];
};
```

It is an automatically generated type of graphql input by a [code generator](https://graphql-code-generator.com/).

I want to use this type to describe the initial values of the form in the front end. Using Formik something like this:

```js
<Formik
  initialValues={
    { email: '', age: null, password: '' } as RegisterInput
  }
>
  {...}
</Formik>
```

The idea is when graphql changes, the type is regenerated and typescript will complain. The problem is that obviously it is not possible to use the type for initial values since initial values can be nullable while the type `RegisterInput` does not allow nullable values.

The question is: Is there a way to describe only keys of the object based on the given type in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Partial<RegisterInput>` will make all properties of the type option (possibly `undefined`).

Comment: Yes this is working. Thank you. Is there also a way to allow null? Using `Partial<RegisterInput>` accepted types for 'age' are restricted to `'number | undefined'`.

Comment: `type Nullable<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] | null; };`